# Custom language in github repository

Tags: git, github, customization, github-linguist

Git shows the percentage of what languages make up a repository. However, for one of my projects I want to use my own custom language. I know I can create a .gitattributes file and place `*.py linguist-language=Python` to make all py files recognized as Python, but how would I make a file extension recognized as my own language, such as Foo? I've tried `*.flm linguist-language=Foo` but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: ["Language Savant. If your repository's language is being reported incorrectly, send us a pull request!"](https://github.com/github/linguist)

Comment: @PeeHaa It isn't being reported incorrectly. I just want to use my own language of my own design.

Comment: I know this is an old question but I would like to know this, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is currently no way to do that.

---

If your **language was already used in hundred of repositories** on github.com, you could [add support for it in the Linguist open source project](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#adding-a-language).

This feature has already been asked twice on the Linguist repository: [#2627](https://github.com/github/linguist/issues/2627) and [#2598](https://github.com/github/linguist/issues/2598). There are, however, some technical and legal concerns to address before this could be implemented (see [#2627](https://github.com/github/linguist/issues/2627) in particular).

Answer (score 2):

You could send PR to this repository (https://github.com/github/linguist). Just adding a language is not difficult, but GitHub staff accepts only languages that are used in many repositories. Let's read contribution document: https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md